# Pure Js (3 input calculated in real time)?

Tags: javascript, html

Build a basic calculator.

```
<html>    
<body>

    <input class="numb1" type=number name="secondBox" value="">

    <input class="numb2" type=number name="secondBox" value="">

    <input class="numb3" type=number name="thirdBox" value="" readonly>

</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a "have someone code for you" website. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its first time to me i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```js
var evN1  = document.getElementById("no1Box");
evN1.addEventListener("input", calculate, false);
var evN2  = document.getElementById("no2Box");
evN2.addEventListener("input", calculate, false);


function calculate() {

  var n1 = document.getElementById("no1Box").value;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("no2Box").value;
  var r = n1/n2;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + r;
  
}
```

```css
body {padding:0;margin:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
div {margin:15px;}
label {display:block;}
input {border:solid 1px #888;font-size:20px;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;outline:none;}
.myInput {box-shadow:0 0 4px green;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <label for="input">Input 1</label>
    <input class="myInput" id="no1Box" type=number name="firstBox" value="">

    <label for="input">Input 2</label>
    <input class="myInput" id="no2Box" type=number name="secondBox" value="">

    <p id="result"/> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Through `document.getElementById("no1Box");` you take the element with the uniquie id that you set on html [see more about getElementById here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and by using `.value` you get the value that you introduced in your input.

After taking the element `var evN2  = document.getElementById("no2Box");` add a listener to him `evN2.addEventListener("input", calculate, false);` and tell what function should execute when the input is changed. [more examples for eventListener here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html><input type='number' id='one' placeholder='00' onblur='calculate()'>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; / &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type='number' id='two' placeholder='00' oninput='calculate()'>
    <input type='number' id='result' placeholder='Result' disabled>

    <script>
    function calculate(){
        var one = document.querySelector('#one').value;
        var two = document.querySelector('#two').value;
        var result = document.querySelector('#result');
        result.value = Math.floor(one/two);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```